# Simplify nested dictionaries

Tags: python

I took Python as my first programming language and I'm reading the book "Python Crash course". There's an exercise where I need to make dictionaries inside a dictionary and print the info of each city.

I'm using Python 3.7.0.
The code below works just intended but I'm trying to find a simpler way to do this. Is there anything I can improve?

```
cities = {
    'viedma': {
        'provincia': 'rio negro',
        'habitantes': 50000,
        'pais': 'argentina',
        },
    'patagones': {
        'provincia': 'buenos aires',
        'habitantes': 20000,
        'pais': 'argentina',
        },
    'caba': {
        'provincia': 'caba',
        'habitantes': 2800000,
        'pais': 'argentina',
        }
    }

for city, info in cities.items():
    print('\nCiudad: ' + city.title())
    k = list(info.keys())
    v = list(info.values())
    count = 0
    for sub_info in k:
        print(str(sub_info.title()) + ': ' + str(v[count]).title())
        count += 1
```

Comment: If you _do_ need to do this kind of lock-step iteration, you can just do `for sub_key, sub_value in zip(k, v):` instead of messing with indexes. Or, when you need the indexes, do `for index in range(len(k))` or `for index, sub_key in enumerate(k)`, instead of counting up the index manually with `+= 1`. But in this case, you don’t need _any_ of that, as explained in John Kugelman’s answer.

Answer (score 2):

The outer loop elegantly iterates over the keys and values in the outer dict. The inner loop should do the same thing. There's no need for the roundabout code to save the keys and values of each inner dict in `k` and `v` and then iterate over them with a manual `count` variable.

```
for city, info in cities.items():
    print('\nCiudad: ' + city.title())
    for name, value in info.items():
        print(name.title() + ': ' + str(value).title())
```